# Generate Windows Phone 8 Crash Dumps

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does anyone know of a way that I can configure a Windows Phone 8 to generate Crash Dumps for applications that are being developed?

I know that we can get access to dumps that are sent to the MS app store, but I need a dump of an application that is still in development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In "App.xaml.cs" class you will find a method called "Application_UnhandledException". This method is launched every time that your app crashes due an unhandled exception. In the event args you will find the error message, stack trace, etc...

Add your logic here to dump the crash (for example, send an email, or store the log in a database, etc...)

BTW, if the exception is recoverable, you can handle the error and don't close the app setting the Handled variable to true:

```
// Recover from the error
e.Handled = true;
```